# How to rewrite async await function using parallel.ForEachAsync in vb.net and why does this code chatGPT recommend doesn't work?

Tags: vb.net

The original code is

```
For Each account In _accounts
    Dim newtask = account.readBalancesAndOrderForEachAccount().ContinueWith(Sub() account.LogFinishTask("Geting Balances and Order", starttime))
    LogEvents("balance and order account " + account.ExchangeStringName + " is being done by task " + newtask.Id.ToString + " " + newtask.ToString)
    tasklist.Add(newtask)
Next


Await Task.WhenAll(tasklist)
```

I want to use Parallel.ForEachAsync

ChatGPT recommend this

```
    Await Parallel.ForEachAsync(_accounts,
Async Function(account)
    Dim newTask = account.readBalancesAndOrderForEachAccount()
    LogEvents($"Starting task {newTask.Id} for account {account.ExchangeStringName}. Task details: {newTask}")
    tasklist.Add(newTask)
    Await newTask
    account.LogFinishTask("Getting Balances and Order", starttime)
End Function)
```

And I got this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC36945 The 'Async' modifier can only be used on Subs, or on Functions that return Task or Task(Of T).  nicehash2   C:\Users\teguh\Dropbox\vb.net\exchanges2.vb 2551    Active
```

Which is a bit confusing. And most samples are in C#.

So what's the correct way?

Comment: Did you try writing an explicit return type on the lambda function?  Normally, VB will infer the return type without any issues, but I think the `Async` confuses it here.  A brief test suggests that you should be able to do that and have it work correctly.

Comment: On the other hand, my brief test also shows that VB ought to be able to infer that your function (declared as `Async`) should be returning `Task`.  What happens if you assign the function to a variable before passing it to `Parallel.ForEachAsync`?

Comment: I'd stick with `Task.WhenAll()`. Awaitable ValueTasks are not exactly supported in VB.NET (i.e., as the exception suggests, you can pass a `Function(T1, T2, TResult)`, but you cannot mark it async, since this requires a return Type of Task<T>) -- Don't trust ChatGPT when it comes to implementations. It may do when building standard boiler plate, otherwise the outcome is a total (assertive) mess (still testing GPT4, though)

Comment: @Jimi You certainly can mark a lambda function as async and have it return `Task`, so I think the issue might be a little more subtle?  Perhaps that an async lambda returning `Task` still isn't quite right for `Parallel.ForEachAsync`?

Comment: @Craig Sure, but the return Type of the Func prototype in all `ParallelForEachAsync` overloads is `ValueTask`, not `Task` or `Task<T>`.  When you mark a VB.NET Function `Async`, the return Type is supposed to be `Task`, not `ValueTask`. You should be able to test this: build a Function, make it return a `ValueTask` Type, then make it `async` and see what happens to the return Type

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the clarification.  (That was my point, it's a little more subtle than not being able to mark the VB function as `Async` and returning `Task`.)